# I want to write a perl function (sub) called "comma" that takes a string as input, splits the string into an array

Tags: perl

I want to write a perl function (sub) called "comma" that takes a string as 
input, splits the string into an array based on commas (ignoring 
white space around the comma), and returns an array of strings.  The 
catch is that any element may be contained in quotes, in which commas 
will be allowed.

### input:

```
hello,"world, yo",matt
```

### output:

```
hello   
"world, yo"    
math
```

### input:

```
one,two,"three,three and a half",          four              ,"five, five and a half",six
```

### output:

```
one    
two    
"three,three and a half"    
four    
"five, five and a half"     
six
```

### My implemented code

```
my $testb = "hello,'world, yo',matt";
print $_, "\n" for split ',', $testb;

my $testc = "one,two,"three,three and a half",          four              ,"five, five and a half",six";
print $_, "\n" for split ',', $testc;
```

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about programming, not about Unix & Linux... But the format you describe sounds like CSV. Have you considered just using a library to parse it as CSV?

Comment: [Text::CSV](http://p3rl.org/Text::CSV)

Comment: *The catch is that any element may be contained in quotes* -- Don't bother with split or single regexps for this, you can't do it that way.  You need a state machine (or else just use the module).

Comment: @celada indeed its a csv formatted input but i want a a subroutine to o/p it the way i want

Comment: Use Text::CSV and avoid reinventing the wheel

Comment: Sounds like you want the `parse_line` function from [Text::ParseWords](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::ParseWords) (which has been part of the standard Perl distribution forever).

Comment: Like most things in Perl, "there's a module for that".

Answer (score 2):

Text::CSV is a better idea! Anyway I like to write Perl...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

sub comma{ my $s=shift;                              ## poor man's CSV
  my %save=();
  my $i=0;
  $s =~ s/(".*?")/$save{++$i}=$1; "--$i--"/ge;       ## save strings
  map {s/--(\d+)--/$save{$1}/r} split(/\s*,\s*/,$s); ## split and restore
}

while(<DATA>){                                       ## testing
  print join("\n---",comma($_)),"\n";
}

__DATA__
one,two,"three,three and a half",  four    ,"five, five and a half",six
```

Comment: Did it compiled for you ? when you pass data in the sub comma ?

Comment: @sam there was a typo in the code (a cut and paste strange "k") could you check it again? (`perl file`)

Comment: What about strings like: `--1--,--2--`?

Comment: @JESUISCHARLIE, ok, ok, I was trying to avoid obfuscating code. Normally  I use non text marks (`$s =~ s/(".*?")/$save{++$i}=$1; "\cA$i\cA"/ge; `) -- you are right of course.

Comment: What about strings like `one,two,"three and a \"half\"",four`?

Comment: @Oesor, good point. That is why I called it "poor man's csv". That specif example is not a problem with "comma"; but `"a\","` would not work.  It is possible to write a regex covering C-strings, or Pascal-strings but not a universal string. (unfortunately is very easy to have problems with standard tools and CSV)